# Why javascript object de-structuring is not working?

Tags: javascript, object, destructuring

I tried to de-structure a object in javascript as following

Example #1

```js
var a, b
var hello = {
  a: 1,
  b: 3
}

({a, b} = hello);
console.log(a);
```

If you hit **Run code snippet** you will encounter

> {   "message": "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'a' of
>   'hello' as it is undefined.",   "filename":
>   "https://stacksnippets.net/js",   "lineno": 18,   "colno": 3 }

Example #2

```js
var a, b
var hello = {
  a: 1,
  b: 3
}

console.log(hello);
({a, b} = hello);
console.log(a);
```

In this experiment i just added a `console.log(hello);` and now de-structuring works fine.

So there is two question

1. In example #1, why it's saying that `hello` is not declared, as it is declared right before de-structuring ?
2. In example #2, why it's working just adding `console.log(hello)` before de-structuring ?

Comment: 1. The parens are trying to call a function, which happens before a value is assigned to `hello`. 2. You put a semi-colon after `console.log`.

Comment: De-structuring syntax causes function call i didn't know that. @Quentin Thanks for that. Could you please let me know more which function is actually called, it has no name specified.

Comment: It's trying to call the object literal as a function. `({a: 1, b: 3}());`

Comment: Now i get it properly. +1 @Quentin

Comment: Add a semicolon after the closing parenthesis of hello object declaration. It'll prevent the next expression from turning into a function call

Comment: Yes i got this, thanks @AdarshHegde